# How to get font size from a Word Style which has no <w:sz>?

Tags: xml, ms-word, styles, openxml

I am working on extraction of format from XML Word files(*.docx), and here is what I encountered.

I found a paragraph style(`<w:pStyle>`) in document part(`document.xml`), which points to a style in styles part(`styles.xml`). The style concerned contains no FontSize tag(`<w:sz>`), and is not based on any other style; the style part contains no default font size(`<w:sz>` in `<w:docDefaults>`), either. While the default font size should be 10.5pt as I heard of it, when opened by Word, the paragraph is shown to be 10pt.  (FYI, the paragraph concerned has no run properties.)

My question is, where in xml can I find this 10pt value? Did I overlook something? Or, is there any way to convert into a "standard" file so that I can get this value right under the corresponding style?

Thank you.

(The file is most possibly created via Word 2007. Here are some other tests done on this file:

By converting its doc counterpart directly into docx (using Word 2010), the same issue still exists;

But by copying the content of this Word into empty document and save, the required FontSize tag did appear under the style concerned.)